# Memory leak in swift while invoking description method of an instance

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments, variadic-functions

Memory leak happens when I call description on the instance logg

```
public func writeLog(logs:AnyObject!...) {
        for i:Int in 0 ..< logs.count {
            if let logg = logs[i] {
                var log:String?=logg.description
                log = nil
            }
        }
}
```

This is how I call

```
writeLog("Hi")
```

*Here is the screenshot of the memory leak from instruments*

[image: Memory leak in instruments]

*Leaks by backtrace*

[image: Memory leak hierarchy]

Any help to resolving the issue is highly appreciated !

Comment: Is writeLog1 same as writeLog?

Comment: Yes ,Now I have edited my question

Comment: Could the problem be in that object's description method?

Comment: What do you see in Instruments if you click the arrow at the end of the address field?  (I think there should be a stack trace that shows exactly where the leaked memory is allocated.)

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - its just a swift string ...so in that case description is its own method.

Comment: @PhillipMills - I have updated the question

Comment: So, something within JavaScript....  Sorry.

Comment: @PhillipMills - I have a JsHandler file which has method  getDeviceLanguage method ...whenever javascript calls getDeviceLanguage it gets intercepted in JSHandler and I call this *writelog* in the method.I don't think it causes memory leak...if I comment out the `var log:String?=logg.description
                log = nil` there is no memory leak

Comment: The problem is not related with javascript because I called the **writelog** from a **viewdidload** of view controller and I am still getting the error.see the [screenshot](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/104795378006016921536/6325358800378470290?icm=false)

Comment: I tried weak and unowned on the function definition `public func writeLog(weak: logs:AnyObject!...) ` and `public func writeLog(unowned: logs:AnyObject!...) ` but still the results are same.

Comment: Guys what do you think of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39349911/730807) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***It's a typecasting problem*** *but I am not sure why AnyObject.description causes.*

instead of this

```
if let logg = logs[i] {
                var log:String?=logg.description
                log = nil
            }
```

try to change your code like this

```
  if let logg = logs[i] as! String{
                var log:String?=logg.description
                log = nil
            }
```

This won't throw any memory leak

so include conditional branches to check for type of the instance and do a typecast and call the description !

Voila !!! :)