# Memory leak in WkWebView instantiation

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

I have a Viewcontroller which contains wkwebview when I pop it from the navigation controller I get memory leak

[image]

The stack trace leads WkWebview instantiation

[image]

I am not using any delegates as well.

I am really wondering what causes this and how to fix this

Comment: I tried in a playground. Simple instantiation of the WKWebView leaks. It's such a strange behaviour. This still happens

Answer (score 3):

It is not observed for a long time (at least I can't remember when I met it last time). Just tested in Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. No leaks - neither in simple test project nor in Playground.

Thus, I assume it should be analysed real usage, which introduces leak.

[image]

Comment: I've figure this out: the deinit happens, but not immediately, for some reason. You can see this if in your playground you assign your `webView` to a weak var, and after `webView = nil` you print the weak var.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza, *deinit happens, but not immediately* - is not a leak... `autoreleasepool` is still alive, and who knows what happens inside WebKit... anyway object has destroyed. And, btw, Playground is just a playground.

Comment: agreed that this is not a leak. Ive observed this behaviour in an unit test and recreated it in a playground. Didn't realise before your answer that the webView was released later. I wrote the same thing with a simple class, and the deist happens immediately. that's why I found it strange. Thanks for your help